# How to get a store email address in php

Tags: magento-1.9, php, email, forms, zend-framework

I made a custom module wich sends a email now i want to edit the module so that it automatically uses one of the store email adresses i saw something like `Mage::app()->getStore()->` but i dont know how to use this to get store mailadress
I use zend

```
    $mail = new Zend_Mail();        
    $mail->setBodyText($bericht);
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->addTo("admin@magento.com", "sales manager");
    $mail->setSubject("Snel offerte");
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
    if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
        $file_size = $_FILES['foto']['size'];
        if (($file_size > 22020096)){
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('Bestand mag niet groter zijn dan 21 MB'));  
        }
        else{
            $fname = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
            $ftempname = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];                   
            $at = new Zend_Mime_Part(file_get_contents($tmpFilePath));
            $at->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
            $at->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
            $at->filename = $fname;             
            $mail->addAttachment($at);
        }
    }
    try {
        $mail->send();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the store mail address in System > Configuration > General > General > Store Information.

Then, to get this setting from your module, you can use the Magento function **Mage::getStoreConfig('contacts/email/recipient_email')**

The function getStoreConfig will allow you to get any configuration, by giving it its XML path.

Answer (score 2):

```
Genral Email

<?php $storeemail=Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email'); ?>

sale email

<?php $saleemail=Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_sales/email'); ?>

Support email

<?php $supportemail=Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/email'); ?>
```